# Percorrer uma tabela (grid) Razor MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, table

Tenho uma tabela que é preenchida por um `Model` no HTML Razor em uma `partialView`, um campo dessa tabela eu deixei como editável usando o `@Html.TextBoxFor`. Após o usuário editar esse campo preciso atualizar no DB, mas primeiro preciso recuperar o valor alterado.

Como posso percorrer a tabela e obter esse valor na `Controller`?

Segue o código da página:

```
<table id="tblLivros" class="table table-hover table-striped" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Livro</th>
            <th>Valor</th>                      
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Livro)
            </td>                                             
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Valor, new { style = "width: 50px;"})
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="form-actions text-right pal">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="Salvar" value="Salvar">
        Salvar Alterações
    </button>
    </div>
```

E da `Controller`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Salvar(ViewModel Livros)
{
    //Percorrer a tabela 
}
```

Comment: Pode colocar por favor o código da *ViewModel* na sua pergunta?

Answer (score 1):

Eu consegui recuperar o valor da grid usando o ajax. Após os valores da grid serem alterados o usuário clica no botão "Salvar Alterações", esse botão executa o `ajax` que percorre a tabela e chama uma função na minha `Controller` que salva as alterações no Banco de Dados.

Segue o código com a solução:

```
<table id="tblLivros" class="table table-hover table-striped" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Livro</th>
        <th>Valor</th>                      
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Livro)
        </td>                                             
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Valor, new { style = "width: 50px;"})
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</tbody>
```

Salvar Alterações

`ajax`:

```html
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
function Salvar() {               
            $("#tblLivros input[type=text]").each(function () {
                var valor = $(this).val();                        
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/Livros/Salvar",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: JSON.stringify({ "valor": valor),
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        success: function (result) {
                            // ...
                        },
                        error: function (request) {
                            // ...
                        }
                    });                
            });
  
      </script>
```

e no `Controller`:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Salvar(decimal valor)
    {
        //Atualiza no DB

        return View();
    }
```

Vlw pessoal!

Answer (score 0):

você pode passar esse valor como parâmetro.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Salvar(string Valor)
{
    //passe o tipo
}
```